# Polyline not showing up on Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps

I am trying to create [a custom URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx) to Bing Maps displaying a polyline. I literally copy-and-pasted the example from their documentation, just modifying it slightly to center the map on the shape, but the polyline isn't showing up :

> https://www.bing.com/maps?sp=polyline.47.68_-122.12_48.68_-123.12_49.68_-122.12_LINE_some%20notes_http://bing.com__%23ff0000__10px_Single_Solid&cp=47.68~-122.12&style=h

What is wrong ?

Comment: Apparently the parameters names remained consistent accross the years, so it does not look like it would be an out-of-date documentation

Comment: Hi @tobiak777, did you succeed in getting the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

That documentation is old and is for the old Bing Maps website. Note that the Bing Maps website is not a developer API/tool. I recommend posting in the Microsoft Answer forums which is geared towards the Microsoft consumer products. The Bing Maps website team is more likely to monitor that forum than a developer forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/bing_maps?auth=1

Since this isn't in the new Bing Maps website, I also recommend adding this to the Bing Listens user voice site as a feature request: https://binglistens.uservoice.com/forums/283355-ideas/category/94066-maps